# How is php xdebug idekey value used during debugging?

Tags: php, ide, xdebug

Various php debugging deocumentations mention how to set the idekey value. 
Some are [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bV0_gk0fkk), [here](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/blob/master/doc/Vdebug.txt#L227) or [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)

> xdebug.idekey
>
> Controls which IDE Key Xdebug should pass on to the DBGp debugger
>   handler.

I am wondering what role this idekey value plays during debugging? How does one know which value to set?

Comment: I think as long as your setting on the server and your client (Eclipse or whatever) are the same, it doesn't matter what the value is.  The main thing is it just needs to match.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/blob/master/doc/Vdebug.txt#L1020) is a good explanation how one IDE implementation uses the idekey.  I understand it is a convention between the xdebug and the ide implementations. I am still wondering if there is a fundamental reason for the idekey though.